# iPhone/Objective-C - Retrieving echoed PHP text from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, nsurl

I have a website that returns an access_token (i.e. Facebook).

The `redirect_uri has` been changed to point to a PHP file on my web server. The PHP code simply echoes the users offline facebook `access_token` to the page.

What would be the best way to grab this `access_token` so I can store it within `NSUserDefaults`?

I'm assuming I'd need to use `UIWebView`'s:

`[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];`

In some way shape or form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a webview! It consumes resources and is slow for that purpose.

Make use of a Framework like [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to fire a http get request or use Apple's [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). You may even consider using https to bring in some security.

Comment: 100% agree with this.  Use of a UIWebView is very bad in this context.  ASIHttpRequest is the way forward.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree you shouldn't use `UIWebView` to do that. To answer your question.

```
NSString *theHTML = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerText"];
```

Before you go use that, I would suggest you use the following solution instead if possible.

```
NSString *theHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

UPDATE:
Alan Zeino point out that using `stringWithContentsOfURL:` is not a very ideal. So I provide another solution that is async. My solution assume everything will work. You have to implements error handling and data reusing mechanism.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // self.data is a NSMutableData property
    [self.data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *theHTML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    self.data = nil;
    // TODO: Its up to you now how you want to handle the HTML.
}
```

To execute the request, use this.

```
NSURLRequest *theURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSURLConnection *theURLConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theURLRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES] autorelease];
```

Comment: The second solution you've given is not ideal; `stringWithContentsOfURL` is a synchronous method and synchronous methods are very, very bad when used in a networking context. He/She should be using an asynchronous NSURLConnection.

Comment: True though, you wouldn't want your system to hang. I'll update with a method that use NSURLConnection. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am surprise to get a down vote for providing 3 different code and solutions that probably solve almost all related problem. If the down voter could explain where he is unhappy with I improve on my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt answer and detailed explanation of why/why not to use. Appreciate all your help.